# add files with specified file extension where basename exits in directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, cp

If I have a directory like so:

```
dir/
 file1.txt
 file2.txt
```

I would like to create `file1.jpg` and `file2.jpg` where both the new jpg are blank

I would then end up with

```
dir/
 file1.txt
 file2.txt
 file1.jpg
 file2.jpg
```

I know I can simply change the extension of the existing files using

```
for f in *.txt; do
cp "$f" "$(basename "$f" .txt).jpg"
done
```

but the resulting jpgs will contain the contents of the original .txt, but I need them the be empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: you might use `touch` instead, i.e., `touch "$(basename "$f" .txt).jpg"`

Comment: of course! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use touch to accomplish this:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    touch "${f/.txt/.jpg}"
done
```